# Prophet model gives error `ValueError: Found NaN in column 'Peak_viewers'` eventhough there are no Nan values

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, facebook-prophet

I try to predict the average viewers of a game using the Prophet model, using the [Twitch games dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rankirsh/evolution-of-top-games-on-twitch). I have added the Peak_viewers, Streamers and Avg_channels as regressors, but I get the error: `ValueError: Found NaN in column 'Peak_viewers'`. But I checked for missing values, so I don't know what's going on.

```
model = Prophet()
model.add_regressor('Peak_viewers')
model.add_regressor('Streamers')
model.add_regressor('Avg_channels')

model.fit(selection)
future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=2, freq='M')
future['Peak_viewers'] = selection['Peak_viewers']
future['Streamers'] = selection['Streamers']
future['Avg_channels'] = selection['Avg_channels']

forecast = model.predict(future)
fig = model.plot(forecast)
```

`selection['Peak_viewers'].isnull().any()` Gives me back `False`

Selection dataframe:

```
ds         y    Hours_Streamed  Peak_viewers    Streamers   Avg_channels
2016-01-01  64378   830105  372654  120849  1117
2016-02-01  64652   754901  235027  106074  1086
2016-03-01  96854   742531  784934  104144  999
2016-04-01  99754   721644  1059002 97614   1003
2016-05-01  60407   663528  347527  101483  893
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2022-09-01  81343   797252  454739  119721  1108
2022-10-01  76181   762067  681874  110356  1025
2022-11-01  120920  666047  1313814 106614  926
2022-12-01  42147   682014  280430  105795  917
2023-01-01  52695   836436  325890  126395  1125
```